# Delete item from list of angular js and database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, codeigniter

hi i am new to angular js. In stage of learning. I had fetched data from database after the json encode. It worked sucessfully. I am using code igniter. Now i want to delete the list fetched from angular js and db too at a same time. But i cannot get any tutorials or i am unable to catch the concept. It would be great if someone could help me.

Actually my logic is to catch the id of the post and pass this id to ci controller and deleting the post according to id by sending it to model. And fetching data from again after the delete from db so that new result would come. Is my logic correct or is there any other efficient way to perform the same task. I cannot pass the post id to ci controller and catch at ci controller.

### app.js

```
 function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http) {
     $http({method: 'POST', 
            url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/get_feedback'; ?>'     
     }).success(function(data) {
         $scope.posts = data; // response data 
     });

     $scope.deleteFeed = function (pId) { 
         //Defining $http service for deleting a list 
         alert(pId); //passing post id
         $http({ method: 'DELETE',
                 url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/del_feedback'; ?>',
                 data : pId     //how can i send this pId to ci controller
         }).success(function (data) {
               $scope.posts = data; // response data 
         });
     }
  }
```

### html

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item feed" ng-repeat="post in posts">                       
        <span style="font-weight: bold">{{post.name}}</span>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">{{post.email}}</span>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">{{post.short_date}}</span>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;color: #aaa;">                            
            {{post.message_summary}}
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del_feedback" ng-click="deleteFeed(post.id)" style="position:absolute;top: 0%;right: 0%;color: #E13300;font-size: 10px;display: none;cursor: pointer;"></span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could always just send the id to delete and on return then splice the item from the object,  if you had a reason to avoid the complete repage. You could probably make a nicer animation that way too.

Comment: Why can't you just pass your `pId` as a query parameter appended to your `url`? Also, what data do you want to fetch from the database after the deletion? You can do the fetch in the `.success` callback of `$scope.deleteFeed`.

Comment: i want to fetch all the records after the success of deletion. Do you mean using query string.

Answer (score 0):

Hi used query string to send id to ci controller.

### angular js function

```
 function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)
 {
 $http({method: 'POST', url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/get_feedback'; ?>'}).success(function(data)
 {
 $scope.posts = data; // response data 
 });


 $scope.deleteFeed = function (pId) { 
 //Defining $http service for deleting a person 
 // alert(pId);
 $http({ method: 'DELETE',
     url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/del_feedback?id='; ?>' + pId 
 }).success(function (data) 
 {

 $http({method: 'POST', url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/get_feedback'; ?>'}).success(function(data)
 {
 $scope.posts = data; // response data 
 });

 });
 }
 }
 //    feedback cont
```

### HTML

```
   <div class="panel-body" id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax" style="height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">


            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item feed" ng-repeat="post in posts">

                    <span style="font-weight: bold">{{post.name}}</span>
                    <!--<span style="font-size: 12px;">{{post.email}}</span>-->
                    <span style="font-size: 12px;" class="pull-right">{{post.short_date}}</span>
                    <br>
                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color: #aaa;">

                        {{post.message_summary}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del_feedback" ng-click="deleteFeed(post.id)" style="position:absolute;top: 0%;right: 0%;color: #E13300;font-size: 10px;cursor: pointer;"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

### CI controller

```
   public function get_feedback()
    {
        $feedback = $this->CmsDbmodel->get_feedback();
        $feedback_json = json_encode($feedback);
        echo $feedback_json;
    }


    public function del_feedback()
    {
        $pid = $_GET['id'];
        $feedback = $this->CmsDbmodel->del_feedback($pid);
    }
```

### CI Model

```
function  get_feedback()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('feedback');
    return $query->result();
}

function  del_feedback($pid)
{
    $this->db->delete('feedback', array('id' => $pid)); 
}
```